# Historic external task logs

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I have a test case which starts a process using Rest API **POST /process-definition/key/{key}/start** with one of invalid variable in the request body. From result response I took Id of the process instance to verify the external task logs using Rest API **GET /history/external-task-log**

In my testing I am expecting **failureLog** as true from the historic external task log for that processId, but actually the response has **deletionLog** as true.

Is this expected behavior or is it a bug ?